# Is it appropriate to ask about project maintenance and architecture?

Tags: discussion

**Executive Sumary**

I'd like to find resources for learning how to maintain a small but non-trivial animation project, such as two or three minute animated film.  Would it be appropriate to open up a question on this?  Or would it be possible to add a "Project Architecture and Maintenance" section to the resources [community wiki](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)?  I'm asking on Meta because I realize this isn't a technical question about Blender, so I'm unsure of its appropriateness.

**TL;DR**

Once upon a time I began learning c++. For a popular language like this, the online resources for learning syntax, best practices, and basic design patterns are exhaustive.  However, I found it quite difficult to move from writing individual "toy" programs to large-scale, useful applications.  Most of what I've learned about the latter--which I eventually found out is called "software architecture"--I picked up from using, reading, and sometimes contributing to open source projects on GitHub.

Now I've been using Blender for a little while, and see myself running into a similar issue.  The online resources and user community for Blender are incredible.  But tutorials tend to be "single-serving" by their nature, focusing on a single object/scene/shot/technique.  What I'd like to understand is how to maintain a project in a way that supports modularity, and is scalable to a still small, but nontrivial project (say a short animated film of a few minutes, but involving multiple scenes and characters).  Are there resources (dedicated tutorials, or perhaps Blender projects on GitHub or elsewhere) where one could learn best practices for maintaining nontrivial projects?

Comment: In general we've avoided these sorts of questions, due to their broad scope and general nature (hard to provide a single definitive answer which applies to all projects). However, having a comprehensive reference for things like tried & tested organization techniques and common best-practices etc. would no doubt be extremely useful. Perhaps creating a canonical community wiki post is in order ([we did something similar for GPU troubleshooting](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/354/599))

Comment: Something like that would be incredibly helpful, especially as asset managers/source control/integration with other apps evolve.  I'm happy to wait and gauge support, or I can go ahead and ask and just see how it is received.